# How to return different relation as the same name in an Api Resource

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

In my project I have set up multiple relationships like :

**Model**

```
public function foo() 
{ 
  return $this->hasMany(Bar::class);
}

public function fooSold() 
{ 
  return $this->hasMany(Bar::class)->where('sold', 1);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function show()
{
  $bar = Bar::with('foo')->first();
  return new BarResource($bar);
}

public function showSold()
{
  $bar = Bar::with('fooSold')->first();
  return new BarResource($bar);
}
```

**Resource**

```
public function toArray($request)
return [
...
'foo' => Foo::collection($this->whenLoaded('foo')),
]
```

Returning the first function in my controller isn't any problem. But how would I return the second one under the same name as 'foo' in my resource ?

```
'foo' => Foo::collection($this->whenLoaded'fooSold')),
'foo' => Foo::collection($this->whenLoaded'foo')),
```

This works but doesn't seem like the right way to do it, since you have the same array keys twice.

What's the best way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [local query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes) for the second case:

```
public function scopeSold($query) 
{ 
    return $query->whereHas('foo', function ($q) { 
        $q->where('sold', 1);
    });
}

// call the scope
$sold = Foo::sold();
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of arrays is to have unique keys. If you want to store pairs of values, then create an array of arrays like:

```
$array[] = [$value1, $value2];
```

In your case, something like:

```
'foo' => [Foo::collection($this->whenLoaded'fooSold')), Foo::collection($this->whenLoaded'foo'))]
```

Comment: This is indeed a possibility but I would have to rewrite a part of my front-end since this returns wrapped in an array. Hence why I selected DigitalDrifter's answer where that isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'foo' => Foo::collection($this->whenLoaded('foo') instanceof MissingValue ? $this->whenLoaded('fooSold') : $this->whenLoaded('foo')),
```